# Spring Data Couchbase - ClassNotFoundException for CustomConversions

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

If *`spring-data-couchbase 3.0.4`* is used the following exception is raised:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/convert/CustomConversions
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
...
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at com.avaya.ept.couchbase.CouchbaseApplication.main(CouchbaseApplication.java:9) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
... 31 common frames omitted
```

*`Couchbase` configuration is default:*

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages={"com.test.couchbase.repositories"})
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

public static final List<String> NODE_LIST = Arrays.asList("couchbase");
public static final String BUCKET_NAME = "test_name";
public static final String BUCKET_PASSWORD = "test_password";

@Override
protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
    return NODE_LIST;
}

@Override
protected String getBucketName() {
    return BUCKET_NAME;
}

@Override
protected String getBucketPassword() {
    return BUCKET_PASSWORD;
}
```

There is no such error if `spring-data-couchbase 2.2.10` is used.

**UPD:**

I found some details. *`spring-data-couchbase 3.0.4`* uses class `org.springframework.core.ReactiveTypeDescriptor` and interface `org.springframework.core.ErrorCoded`. The class has been added in Spring 5.0.0 release, the interface has been removed from Spring 5.0.0 release.
What Spring release do I need to use to use *`spring-data-couchbase 3.0.4`*?

Comment: could you share your dependency tree?

Comment: @Makoton I've added some notes to the topic. Thank you.

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question? I'm using sprint boot version 1.5.9 and I also have the same problem with ReactiveTypeDescriptor and I'm using spring-data-couchbase 3.0.5.